# how to randomly select from list of variables (bitmaps) with incremental names using Iterator and/or loop ? (java, blackberry, bb)

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a big list (say about thousand) of .png bitmaps with incremental names:

```
_image1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("a1.png");
_image2 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("a2.png"); 
_image3 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("a3.png");
  ...
_image999 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("a999.png");
_image1000 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("a1000.png");
```

I need a code to select one bitmap and attach it to BitmapField *myBitmapField*, when integer *myCounter* obtains random value from 1 to 1000. I could do it by checking value of *myCounter* thousand times by using **if** and **else** :

```
if (myCounter == 1)
   myBitmapField.setBitmap(_image1);
else if (myCounter == 2)
   myBitmapField.setBitmap(_image2);
else if (myCounter == 3)
   myBitmapField.setBitmap(_image3);
  ...
else if (myCounter == 1000)
   myBitmapField.setBitmap(_image1000);
```

But that would be very long code. Is there a way of doing it using **Loop** and/or **Iterator**  ? Something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 1000) 
 { 
   i = i + 1;
   if (myCounter == i)
    myBitmapField.setBitmap(_image[i]); 
 }
```

Is there an easy and short way of doing it ? Thank you very much for help! (Java for blackberry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about dynamically generating the name, like

```
myBitmapField.setBitmap(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("a" + myCounter + ".png"));
```

If you're concerned about resource duplication, you can check a cache first.